# How can I give list of permitted values for an enum attribute of Ant Task

Tags: java, ant, enums

I am writing a custom task by extending Task.java from Apache Ant.  I have a requirement of passing some enum values in one of the attributes of the task.

Lets say I have an enum Foo with values {A, B, C} and I have attribute optionType that accepts enum Foo in its setter method.  Below is how my custom task looks -

```
   public Enum Foo{ A, B, C}

   public class MyTask extends Task {
       String optionType;

       public setOptionType(Foo f) {
           this.optionType = f.getName();
       }
    }
```

Now when I use the optionType attribute in my build.xml with some invalid option as follows -

```
<myTask optionType="D"/>
```

Ant correctly gives me error

> 'D' is not a permitted value for Foo"

This is fine but is there way where I can catch error in my custom task code and list out the the permitted values for `Foo`?  Currently it seems that the default message is lacking more information and I want to customize it.

Below is the stackTrace for call sequence in Ant -

```
at org.apache.tools.ant.IntrospectionHelper$12.set(IntrospectionHelper.java:1232)
at org.apache.tools.ant.IntrospectionHelper$AttributeSetter.setObject(IntrospectionHelper.java:1502)
at org.apache.tools.ant.IntrospectionHelper.setAttribute(IntrospectionHelper.java:405)
at org.apache.tools.ant.RuntimeConfigurable.maybeConfigure(RuntimeConfigurable.java:388)
at org.apache.tools.ant.RuntimeConfigurable.maybeConfigure(RuntimeConfigurable.java:344)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.maybeConfigure(Task.java:202)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.configure(UnknownElement.java:196)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.java:163)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:347)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
```

Answer (score 0):

> is there way where I can catch error in my custom task code and list out the the permitted values for Foo?

This doesn't seem to be possible because the exception occurs at a stage where the execution of the task has not even started. It occurs in the *introspection helper* code which maps between the task attributes and the setter methods before calling the custom task. The only possible solution I see is to patch Ant by changing the `IntrospectionHelper` class (the API documentation does not encourage changing this class, so make sure what you need is worth the change and that you run some tests to make sure nothing breaks). The exception stack trace should help locate where the `enum` is evaluated so you customize the error message there.

The other option is to have the task invocation placed in a [`trycatch`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/trycatch.html) block, which is provided in Ant-Contrib. You can display the error message in the `catch` block in this case. If you don't want to place `trycatch` around each and every call to the custom task, you can create a wrapper `macrodef` that centralizes the call:

```
<macrodef name="myTaskMacro">
   <attribute name="optionType"/>   
   <sequential>
      <trycatch property="foo" reference="bar">
          <try>
             <myTask optionType="@{optionType}"/>
          </try>

          <catch>
             <echo>Error message...</echo>
          </catch>
       </trycatch>  
   </sequential>
</macrodef>
```